# i configured identity for roles user and admin but i can just login with roles user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use identity framework and identity framework ui for my application, and i configured identity for roles user and admin but i can just login with roles user.
when i login with account role admin then button login is not active, maybe is it.
but when i login with account role user or register new account then i can login and go to home page my application
This is my code.

program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Client.Data;
using Client.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'AuthDbContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();

// Add services to the container.
var connectString1 = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntitiesDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'EntitiesDbContextConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EntitiesDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectString1));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var roles = new[] { "Admin", "User" };
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
        }
    }
}
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    string email = "admin@admin.com";
    string password = "Admin@123";
    if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) == null)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.Email = email;
        user.UserName = email;
        await userManager.CreateAsync (user,password);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    }
}

app.Run();
```

Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

@* <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1> *@
@* <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to log in.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins!)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div> *@
<div class="container-fluid vh-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="row vh-100">
        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-gray p-5 text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center fw-bolder fs-2">Register</h4>
            <p class="mb-3 fs-7">Register Now and Fell the New Digital World</p>
            <a href="/Identity/Account/Register">
                <button class="btn fw-bold mb-5 btn-outline-success px-4 rounded-pill">
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </a>
            <div class="img-cover p-4">
                <img src="~/Content2/assets/images/loginbg.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 p vh-100">
            <div class="row d-flex vh-100">
                <div class="col-md-8 p-4 ikigui m-auto text-center align-items-center">
                    <h4 class="text-center fw-bolder mb-4 fs-2">Login</h4>
                    <section>
                        <form id="account" method="post">
                            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true"
                                       placeholder="name@example.com" />
                                <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password"
                                       aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                                <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                                <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                                    Log in
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </section>

                    <p class="text-center py-4 fw-bold fs-8">
                        Or Sign in with social platforms
                    </p>

                    <ul class="d-inline-block mx-auto">
                        <li class="float-start px-3">
                            <a href=""><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="float-start px-3">
                            <a href=""><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="float-start px-3">
                            <a href=""><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="float-start px-3">
                            <a href=""><i class="bi bi-google"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using Client.Areas.Identity.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignUser
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <h1>this is view for admin</h1>
    
}
else
{
    <h1>this is view of user</h1>
    
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using Client.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Client.Controllers
{
    
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();  
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create an application with more than one role. specifically, I'm expecting to have 2 roles.
I tried to work with identity framework, and it was not as expected.

Everyone also see it on Github in branch "demo-working-with-idenity": https://github.com/toiQS/Noname/tree/demo-working-with-identity